# Roslyn suppressor не определяется в Rider

Tags: c#, rider, roslyn

Пишу свой suppressor(подавитель?), основанный на Roslyn для подавления предупреждений. в Visual Studio с Resharper он работает, а в IDE Rider - нет. В списке Roslyn анализаторов в настройках мой suppressor просто не появляется.

В то же время обычный анализатор появляется в списке анализаторов и работает как задумано.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, может быть кто-то занимался этим и знает в чем может быть проблема.

[Вот тут информация о подавлении предупреждений](https://gist.github.com/mavasani/fcac17a9581b5c54cef8a689eeec954a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Rider подавители Roslyn не поддерживаются. 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-45021 - тикет на реализацию.